# Nested .then()'s Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, promise

I'm having some difficulty in simplifying the readability of the code I have written, so far I have managed to separate the code into two primary functions, however I'm still suffering with nested .then()'s. I'm not sure if there is any simpler way of writing these two functions. Any advice on structure and pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.

I should also highlight that the horsePostHandler.init() function is referring to a different module. The function init() shown in this example is part of the racePostHandler.

**RacePostHandler.js**

```
function createHorseEntities( raceEntity ) {
    promises = horsePostHandler.init(raceEntity, race.Horse)
    _.each(promises, function( promise ){
        promise.then(function( entity ){
            if ( raceEntity.horses.length === 0 ) {
                controller.update({ "horseUpdate": true, "horseEntity": entity }, raceEntity)
            }
        })
    })
    return raceEntity
}
function init( object ) {
    handler.data = object.data.PARaceCardObject ? object.data.PARaceCardObject : object.data.PABettingObject;
    racePromises = _.map(handler.data.Meeting.Race, function( race ) {
        return Promise.all([ getMeeting(object.promise), controller.find({ x_reference: race.ID }) ])
        .spread(function( meetingEntity, raceEntity ) {
            return doesRaceExist(meetingEntity, raceEntity, race)
        })
        .then(createHorseEntities)
        .catch(errorHandler)
    })
    return racePromises
}
```

**HorsePostHandler.js**

The main reason why I separated the RacePostHandler and the HorsePostHandler into individual modules was due to them using different controllers. One interacting with a Race model, the other a Horse model.

```
function init( raceEntity, horseArray ) {
    promises = _.map(horseArray, function( horse ) {
        return controller.find({name: horse.Name})
        .then(function(horseEntity){
            return doesHorseExist(raceEntity, horseEntity, horse)
        })
    })
    return promises
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `_.each` with promises.

Comment: My current code works perfectly with _.each. However, I'm just doing some house keeping, and was struggling with the restructure. The horsePostHandler returns an array of fulfilled promises that I needed to iterate over. If you have any other alternatives to getting the values from the array of fufilled promises please feel free to explain.

Comment: The problem with `each` is that `createHorseEntities` does not return a promise that allows one to wait until the controller has done all updates. Like you did in `init`, better apply `map` and use `Promise.all`.

Comment: "*I'm still suffering with nested .then()'s*" - I must be missing something, but the code you posted does not contain any nested `then` callbacks?

Comment: Maybe it's just me being over analytical of my own work here. So the reason why I got into this mindset was the entire createHorseEntities function was nested directly in the .then() below.spread() in the init() function. Maybe I'm wanting to oversimplify something that doesn't require it.

Comment: Yeah, there's really nothing wrong with that - and notice the `then` is *below* the `spread` callback, so no nesting. The only weird thing is returning an array of promises where you'd usually return a promise for an array.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out, that is something I need to review. My horsePostHandler.init function is not returning a promise, its just returning an array of promises from a _.map function. I'll update my post, but I think I can solve that one myself. - Updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing nodejs 7, you can start with [--harmony-async-await](https://blog.risingstack.com/async-await-node-js-7-nightly/) flag.

This allows the new async / await functionality which is much more readable:

```
async function run() {
    try {
        let result1 = await myFirstPromise
        let moreResults = await Promise.all([mySecondPromise, myThirdPromise)
        let finalResult = await lastPromise
        finalResult = doSomethingWith(finalResult)
        return finalResult    
   } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err)
   }
}

run()
```

In your example using latest javascript (ES7 i think) would be:

```
 async function createHorseEntities( raceEntity ) {
       for (let entity of (await horsePostHandler.init(raceEntity, race.Horse))) {
            if ( raceEntity.horses.length === 0 ) {
                controller.update({ "horseUpdate": true, "horseEntity": entity} , raceEntity)
            }
       }
       return raceEntity;
  }
```

Comment: Paul you really didn't have to rewrite my code for me, I was planning on playing around with it myself. Again your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is a bit strange that the then() is inside the _each. If horsePostHandler.init(raceEntity, race.Horse) returns Promise.all(array of promises) as i understand from your comment, I would rewrite it like this.

```
    function createHorseEntities( raceEntity ) {
       horsePostHandler.init(raceEntity, race.Horse)
         .then( function(entities) {
           _.each(entities, function( entity ){
                if ( raceEntity.horses.length === 0 ) {
                    controller.update({ "horseUpdate": true, "horseEntity": entity} , raceEntity)
                }
            })
        })
        return raceEntity
    }
```

Reads more like "first init() then do something with each value".